# jQuery running function inside $(document).ready(function() {

Tags: jquery, document-ready, onload-event

What am I doing wrong here? why `writeQuestions` doesn't run on-load (not onclick..)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON("JavaScript/questions.json", function(data) {questions = data;});
    $("#start").one("click" , writeQuestions);
    writeQuestions();

 });
```

(the `.one()` line is commented out in my code)

When i do this:`window.onload=writeQuestions;` it works fine..

Comment: are your questions loaded in the .getJSON()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

writeQuestions() is running before the JSON result is returned.  Put the function call in the callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     $.getJSON("JavaScript/questions.json", 
          function(data) { questions = data; writeQuestions(); }
     ); 
});
```

Also, I would recommend updating the writeQuestions() function to accept a parameter, and passing the questions that way.  I am surprised it ever worked, since there are variable scope issues.

Comment: it works! but how do I know that the result is not returned yet? isn't it suppose to be returned before it executes `writeQuestions` in my code?

Comment: @ilyad No, the getJSON function runs asynchronously.  It starts doing that and continues with the rest of your code.  The anonymous function that you provide in the getJSON call is what runs after the result is returned.  This is where you put the code that needs the received data.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried...

```
$.getJSON("JavaScript/questions.json", function(data) {
    questions = data;
    writeQuestions();
});
```

In your example `writeQuestions` will be called before the `getJSON` call has returned.

**Edit** as Fosco pointed out in his answer, you are declaring `questions` as a global variable here as you do not use the `var` keyword. This might work but it is not good practice and is bug prone. It would be better to re-write as:

```
$.getJSON("JavaScript/questions.json", function(data) {
    writeQuestions(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

are your questions loaded in the .getJSON()? 
IF so, try putting in a  success

```
$.getJSON("JavaScript/questions.json", function(data) {
    questions = data;
}).success(function() {writeQuestions();)
```